# Am I right in interpreting the part in bold?

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation

> Everard Gault had been missing in 1915; and waiting, not knowing, had
> been the loneliest time of Heloise’s life, her two-year-old baby her greatest
> comfort. Then a telegram had come, and soon afterwards **she had closed
> her eyes in selfish relief when there was the news that her husband had
> been invalided out of the army. As long as they lived, she vowed to herself,
> she would never again be parted from him, her resolve an expression of
> her gratitude for this kind misfortune.**

Is "close your eye **to** something" the same as "close your eye **in** something"?

And does the part in bold mean: when there was the news that her husband had been invalided out of the army she was not proud and selfish of this relief and vowed to herself that as long as they lived she would never again be parted from him and in this kind of misfortune she decided to show her gratitude because of that time and not to be parted from her husband?

Source: The Story Of Lucy Gault by William trevor

Answer (score 2):

In ***she had closed her eyes in selfish relief***, *in selfish relief* is describing the ***manner (how?)*** she closed her eyes. "***in*** selfish relief" could also be expressed by "***with*** selfish relief" which may be more comprehensible for non-natives, but less idiomatic.
The author means that she was relieved by the fact that her husband was [***invalided***](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&sxsrf=ALeKk02t8GRxBsBm2LLIPMgGstd7EO2qYw%3A1607770873891&ei=-aLUX9zuNeHdxgOti5mAAw&q=invalided%20out%20of%20the%20war&oq=invalided&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgBMgUIABDJAzICCAAyAggAMgcIABCxAxAKMgIIADIHCAAQsQMQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIKCC4QxwEQrwEQCjoFCAAQkQI6CwgAELEDEIMBEJECOgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOggIABCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6CAguELEDEIMBOgQIIxAnOgsIABCxAxDJAxCRAjoHCAAQsQMQQzoFCC4QsQM6AgguOggIABCxAxDJAzoICC4QxwEQrwFQgITRAVjCltEBYKWp0QFoAHAAeACAAZIEiAHIEZIBCzAuMy4yLjIuMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab) from the army, and this was ***selfish*** because, although her husband must have gone through physical suffering and lost his career, she was only thinking of her own advantage of having him back home.

As for the rest of the passage in bold, you can see a ellipsis there:

> As long as they lived, she vowed to herself, she would never again be parted from him, her resolve ***(being)*** an expression of her gratitude for this kind misfortune.

Her resolve not to depart from her husband for the rest of her life is the expression of her gratitude for the fact that he is coming back home due to unfortunate circumstances.
I like the use of the oxymoron ***kind misfortune***. It is a *misfortune* for her husband and for her (if she shares in the suffering of her husband in any way), but it is a *kind* one for her, because they are reunited.